# Google Sheets - Assigning numerical value to colored cell and then SUM values together in another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, colors, google-sheets-formula

I am unsure as to whether this can be done but I am looking to try and assign a numerical value to a specific color and then SUM the values and display the result in a different column.

[image: Example of required output]

The image above would be the ideal output with Green + Green + Grey = 7 and Green + Red + Green = 6.
I would like to be able to assign any cell with the green color with 3, grey cells with 1 and red cells with 0 and then add them up to be displayed in the Total Monthly Points column I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use a **custom formula** that uses [getBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) to get the **Hexadecimal** value of the cell's background color and calculate the total number of points according to a mapping between colors and points:

```
function getPoints(row, column) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  const start_cell = sh.getDataRange().getCell(row, column);    
  const cells_range = start_cell.offset(0, 0, 1, 3);
  const cells_bg = cells_range.getBackgrounds().flat();    
  const colors_src_range = sh.getRange('C1:E1');
  const colors_source = colors_src_range.getBackgrounds().flat();
  const colors_pts = colors_src_range.getValues().flat().map(cv=>cv.replace( /^\D+/g, ''));

  var total_pts = 0;  
  cells_bg.forEach(cbg=>{
  colors_source.forEach( (col,index)=>{
  total_pts += cbg == col ? parseInt(colors_pts[index]) : 0
  });})
  
  return total_pts;
}
```

Then you can use it as a formula in your sheet: `getPoints(row, column)` for which you need to specify the coordinates of the very left cell that has color (**Column C** in your example) and it will return the total number of points of the color row.

### **Updates:**

- the Hexadecimal values are picked up by the script automatically from
  the range `C1:E1`, therefore you don't need to manually pass the
  values.
- the points per color are also picked up by the script automatically
  using regular expressions.
- code is more optimized because it uses [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) instead of [getBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground).

---

### Example:

For example, this formula:

```
=getPoints(row(C6),column(C6))
```

will result to this:

[image: example]

---

### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this function will fail big time, if used for anything more than 1k rows. Long functions is a bad idea. Mixing those long functions with custom functions is a even more bad idea.

Comment: @TheMaster the formula is indeed long but I don't think it is heavy. It is a sum of three values according to if conditions. The best solution would be to instead have an onEdit function to do the heavy lifting under the hood. Then formulas wouldn't be needed. But I didn't want to touch so many concepts for an abstract question. Or even have a regular function to run everytime you want to calculate the total points. However, the question itself is abstract anyways.

Comment: It is heavy. You're making 9  custom function calls per cell/formula. Read the documentation about custom function optimization(the link you posted)

Comment: @TheMaster that is true indeed. I updated my answer. If OP wants something more futureproof/stable then I will write a regular function to calculate the points.

Comment: @TheMaster I want to avoid suggesting overcomplicated solutions  to a person with (possibly) no familiarity with GAS to understand concepts like onEdit functions, or for loops, GAS libraries etc and `modify` a google script if he needs to. In my solution I post a structured article where he can see what this custom function does and how he could approach his current situation.

Comment: Custom functions can handle many rows without issue.  You don't need onEdit/regular function with menus. To be clear, I'm specifically against  your specific implementation of this custom function and the builtin formula integration and not against all custom functions in general.

Comment: @TheMaster True. I updated my answer. Please review it and let me know what you think.

Comment: @Marios Thank you. Your updated answer seemed to do the trick and is working. The only issue is that if I need to make revisions to the colors of the cells I then need to go back into the script and re-save it for the figures to update. Is there any way of automating this?

Comment: @Arsenic_Gooner yes there is way. I will update my answer within the next 2 hours .

Comment: @Marios Thank you. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Much better. If you'd still like to optimize further, make the function support arrays: `=GETPOINTS(C6:E7)`, Also use `getBackgrounds()` 1 call instead of multiple `getBackground()` calls in a loop. But I think it's way way better than what you initially had. Good job!

Comment: @TheMaster I updated my answer to take advantage of `getBackgrounds()`, although I kept the argument structure as it was. Thanks a lot again for the recommendations. You really helped me improve my answer.